# Rename a external file in a SAS macro

Tags: sas

I am getting a generic 'Statement not valid or out of order' message with the below:

```
%macro test;
data _null_;
%if %sysfunc(fileexist("C:\report_201809.xlsx")) = 1 %then %do;
rc=%sysfunc(rename("C:\report_201809.xlsx",
"C:\report_201809.xlsx"_old.xlsx",'file'));
%end;
%mend;

%test;
```

Comment: You don't need the `%` signs or `sysfunc` around functions within a data step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below should get you what you need. While you can use `%if` statements in a data step you generally won't need to. I'm guessing the error is coming from the `%sysfunc` function around the `fileexist` and `rename` functions. `%sysfunc` allows you to call data step functions outside of a data step so it is not needed here.

```
%macro test;
data _null_;
if fileexist("C:\file.txt") then do;
    rc = rename("C:\file.txt", "C:\file2.txt", 'file');
end;
run;
%mend;
```

Alternatively, you could use an [X Command](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/69955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n14rxpt7iu6iksn17r895o6kcpgi.htm) that allows you to execute Windows commands. You could replace the `rename` function with the following statement.

```
x move C:\file.txt C:\file2.txt;
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion (using rename, not X) i get same error.

Comment: @Victor Try removing the macro statements and see if that works. Also, post your updated code. I can't see why there would be any issue.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `DATA _NULL_` or proceed per @J_Lard.

Macro arguments used in `%sysfunc` invoked function calls are implicitly quoted and do not need additional `'` or `"`

```
%macro test;
  %local rc;
  %if %sysfunc(fileexist(C:\report_201809.xlsx)) = 1 %then %do;
    %let rc = %sysfunc(rename(C:\report_201809.xlsx,C:\report_201809_old.xlsx,file));
  %end;
%test;
```

You original code may have worked (by way of non-obvious side effect) if the filename `"C:\report_201809.xlsx"_old.xlsx"` (having an extraneous `"`) was corrected to `"C:\report_201809_old.xlsx"`